# VS Code - Warning - "auth' is not defined for Firebase-auth.js loaded with CDN in index.html

Tags: firebase, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, cdn

Working on this tutorial from the The Net Nija [Firebase Auth Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jUPIes_B8vRjn1_GaplOPQ)

VSCode is giving me these warnings for the Firebase variables that I brought in from a CDN.

How do you get VSCode to recognize them?

Check it out.

```
index.html
...
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.6/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

<script>

  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxx",
    authDomain: "xxx",
    databaseURL: "xxx",
    projectId: "xxx",
    storageBucket: "xxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxx",
    appId: "xxxxx"
  }

  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  const auth = firebase.auth()
  const db = firebase.firestore()

</script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/auth.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

in auth.js VScode starts complaining

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => { <!-- 'auth' is not defined --VScode warning -->
  if (user) {
    setupUi(user)
    // get data
    db.collection('guides').         <!-- 'db' is not defined --VScode warning -->
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        setUpGuides(snapshot.docs)
      })
  } else {
    setupUi()
    setUpGuides([])
  }
})
```

....

Why is that?

Is VScode not reading the Firebase CDN's?

Can this be fixed?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: VScode is complaining that it doesn't know where you are defining `auth`, you can instead of doing it on the initial script, go to your `auth.js` file and define it there, `firebase` is working as global, your `const auth` is not... TL;DR, move `const auth = firebase.auth()` to `scripts/auth.js`

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful and fixed the auth and db warnings, of course now i'm getting warnings about firestore not defined, do you think im better off just importing the CDN in the auth file? also what did you mean by ...TL:DR move?